# In a Django migration, how can I create an object and use it as default in another field?

Tags: python, django

I already have a model `Area`. I want to add a new model `City`, like:

```
class City(models.Model):
    pass

class Area(models.Model):
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.PROTECT) # new field.
```

How to create a migration which sets the existing areas to a city (called 'Mumbai')?

I know I can do `migrations.RunPython` but how do I get the new city's id to pass to `models.ForeignKey`'s `default` param?

```
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='area',
            name='city',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=???, to='location.City'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized, the `models.ForeignKey(default=???)` param can be a callable, so I created the city in `RunPython` and used a callable to get its `id`.

Full code:

```
class CityObjectHolder:
    @classmethod
    def get_object_id(cls):
        return cls.city_object.id

    @classmethod
    def create(cls, apps, schema_editor):

        # We get the model from the versioned app registry;
        # if we directly import it, it'll be the wrong version
        City = apps.get_model('location', 'City')
        db_alias = schema_editor.connection.alias
        cls.city_object = City.objects.create(name='Mumbai')
        print(f'created city with id: {cls.city_object.id}')


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('location', '0011_auto_20200403_2212'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='City',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('name', models.TextField(unique=True)),
                ('json_data', django.contrib.postgres.fields.jsonb.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)),
                ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
                ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.RunPython(CityObjectHolder.create),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='area',
            name='city',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=CityObjectHolder.get_object_id, on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.PROTECT, to='location.City'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

`RunPython` ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#runpython

Using anything besides a callable for `models.ForeignKey(default=???)` wasn't working because that code was getting executed before `CityObjectHolder.create` was executed.